# How to Delete extra character from a string in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new to T-SQL. I need your help to remove extra characters from string or rows from a column I am extracting after Pivoting.

String looks like : `?<span style="color:rgb background color then actual string.`
I want to remove these extra/special character while extracting the data.

I could only find to remove/replace from the beginning or end of the string but not sure how to remove the above character's from the string

Thanks

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use the REPLACE() function?

Comment: `String looks like : ?` <= Is the question not finished or is the string a literal question mark character?

Comment: What are the "Extra/special characters"? Maybe you could share your before and after

Answer (score 0):

Grab a copy of [patexclude8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/T-SQL/117890/)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.PatExclude8K
(
  @String VARCHAR(8000),
  @Pattern VARCHAR(50)
) 
/*******************************************************************************
 Purpose:
 Given a string (@String) and a pattern (@Pattern) of characters to remove, 
 remove the patterned characters from the string.

Usage:
--===== Basic Syntax Example
 SELECT CleanedString 
 FROM dbo.PatExclude8K(@String,@Pattern);

--===== Remove all but Alpha characters
 SELECT CleanedString 
 FROM dbo.SomeTable st
 CROSS APPLY dbo.PatExclude8K(st.SomeString,'%[^A-Za-z]%');

--===== Remove all but Numeric digits
 SELECT CleanedString
 FROM dbo.SomeTable st
 CROSS APPLY dbo.PatExclude8K(st.SomeString,'%[^0-9]%');

 Programmer Notes:
 1. @Pattern is not case sensitive (the function can be easily modified to make it so)
 2. There is no need to include the "%" before and/or after your pattern since since we 
    are evaluating each character individually

 Revision History:
 Rev 00 - 10/27/2014 Initial Development - Alan Burstein

 Rev 01 - 10/29/2014 Mar 2007 - Alan Burstein
        - Redesigned based on the dbo.STRIP_NUM_EE by Eirikur Eiriksson
          (see: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1585850-391-2.aspx)
        - change how the cte tally table is created 
        - put the include/exclude logic in a CASE statement instead of a WHERE clause
        - Added Latin1_General_BIN Colation
        - Add code to use the pattern as a parameter.

 Rev 02 - 11/6/2014
        - Added final performane enhancement (more cudo's to Eirikur Eiriksson)
        - Put 0 = PATINDEX filter logic into the WHERE clause

Rev 03 - 5/16/2015
        - Updated code to deal with special XML characters
*******************************************************************************/
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
WITH
E1(N) AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) AS X(N)),
itally(N) AS 
(
  SELECT TOP(CONVERT(INT,LEN(@String),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
  FROM E1 T1 CROSS JOIN E1 T2 CROSS JOIN E1 T3 CROSS JOIN E1 T4
) 
SELECT NewString =
((
  SELECT SUBSTRING(@String,N,1)
  FROM iTally
  WHERE 0 = PATINDEX(@Pattern,SUBSTRING(@String COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,N,1))
  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
).value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'));
GO
```

I'm not clear exactly what characters you want to get rid of or keep but here's 
some examples (note my comments):

```
-- remove letters:
SELECT * FROM dbo.PatExclude8K('abc123!', '[a-zA-Z]');
-- Returns: 123!
;
-- remove numbers:
SELECT * FROM dbo.PatExclude8K('abc123!', '[0-9]');
--Returns: abc!
;
-- only include letters and numbers 
SELECT * FROM dbo.PatExclude8K('###abc123!!!', '[^0-9a-zA-Z]');
--Returns: abc123
;
-- Remove spaces (note the spaces):
SELECT * FROM dbo.PatExclude8K('XXX 123 ZZZ', ' ');
--Returns: XXX123ZZZ
;
-- only include letters and "!, ? or ."
SELECT * FROM dbo.PatExclude8K('123# What?!... ', '[^a-zA-Z!?.]');
--Returns: What?!...
```